# How do you delete variables in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays

How do you delete variables in a c++ program? i have a simple `int list[10];` and i want delete it and change it to `int list[9]`. i would use vectors, but i still want to know how to do it

Comment: Well, how did you create this variable? With or without new? Why can't you simply use that int[10]? Your question indicates, that you probably do not know what you are talking about. In that case, where did you came from? Java? Or Python? Iff Java, then this question is somehow similar to this: "How do I delete an int? I want to change it to a char." Please, describe what you want to do in a programming language you know, then someone can show you the alternatives in c++. My answer would have been: Just cast it, the result of the sizeof operator only depends on the type.

Answer (score 13):

If you have something declared like this:

```
int list[10];
```

there is no way to "delete" it. It is either a global variable, with statically allocated storage, or it is a local variable with storage on the stack.

I don't know exactly what you are trying to accomplish, but maybe something like this will help you figure it out:

```
int *list = new int[10];  // allocate a new array of 10 ints
delete [] list;           // deallocate that array
list = new int[9];        // allocate new array with 9 ints
```

As you suggest in your question, you will almost always be better off using `std::vector`, `std::list`, and the like rather than using raw C-style arrays.

Answer (score 5):

This is not called deleting a variable but instead redefining the type of a variable.  This is simply not possible in C++.  Once a variable type has been established it cannot be changed.

There are several ways to emulate or work around this behavior ...

- Create a child scope and define a new variable of the same name with a different type.
- Switch `list` to an `int*` and allocate it's memory on the heap.  This will have the effect of redefining it to a different size without changing it's type.

Answer (score 2):

If your array is allocated on the heap, then:

```
int *L = new int[10];
delete[] L;
L = new int[9];
```

There is no concept of "deleting" a local variable declared on the stack.

Answer (score 2):

To delete an array in C++ you'd use the `delete[]` operator.  See [this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/new/operator%20delete%5B%5D/).

You'll want to be careful.  What you have is a static array.  When you use `delete` or `delete[]` it must be on dynamically allocated variables (ones you made with `new`).  To do that:

```
int* list = new int[10];
//...Code...
delete[] list;
list = new int[9];
```

Don't forget to `delete` if you `new`! (Ideally you should use something managed so you can't forget, like you said).

Comment: Aww, everyone else beat me, but for the record, `new` is *how* you allocate things on the heap (which is just memory that you get at runtime since the compiler doesn't know how bit it is).

Answer (score 2):

Your
`int list[10];` is a static one. Arrays that are declared as variables are static objects in C++, and you can't delete/create them... it's a compile time thing.

You need to explicitly declare your array as an array object, say

```
int *list=new int[10];
```

Although it still seams a declaration, it's not: the new operand will trigger mem-allocation code)...
If you want to allocate more or less space you need to free it first:

```
delete[] list;
```

and then use the new operand to make a new on (of the same `int` type)

Answer (score -2):

Of course, you could always do this:

```
{
  int list[10];
  ... 'list' has 10 elements ...

  {
    int list[9];
    ... 'list' has 9 elements ... other 'list' inaccessible
  }
  ... 'list' 10 elements ... other 'list' non-existent.
}
```

Can't imagine why you would though.